# Add a custom item above logout item in Woocommerce my account menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, menuitem, hook-woocommerce

I've been googling for a while now, but I can't seem to find an answer, nor anyone else with the same issue. I'm trying to add a menu item, "My Files", above the "Logout" item.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
// Add Menu Item
function my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    return array_merge(
        array_slice( $items, 0, count( $items ) - 1 ),
        array( 'my-files' => 'My Files' ),
        array_slice( $items, count( $items ) - 1 )
    );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_account_menu_items', 10, 1);
```

I've tried calling the filter in a different way, without the last two arguments. I've also tried doing

```
function my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    $items['my-files'] = 'My Files';
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_item_to_my_account_menu', 30, 1 );
function add_item_to_my_account_menu( $items ) {
    $new_items = array();
    // Loop throu menu items
    foreach( $items as $key => $item ){
        if( 'customer-logout' == $key )
            $new_items['my-files'] = __( 'My Files' );

        $new_items[$key] = $item;
    }
    return $new_items;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: I've tried it and it's still not working. The code is in my functions.php, which I should've mentioned in my post above. I also tried clearing my browser cache, but it didn't help.

Comment: @TarikDruskic So your theme (or some plugin) is certainly involved in that issue, with their respective customizations. This code is classic and almost work everywhere. So you may contact your theme support threads…

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and working:

```
function custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {

    $new_items = array();
    foreach($items as $key => $value){
        if($key != 'customer-logout'){
            $new_items[$key] = $value;
        }else{
            $new_items['my-files'] = 'My Files';
            $new_items[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $new_items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_my_account_menu_items' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just make sure login stays at the bottom by unsetting it and adding it back last thing.

```
//keep logout the last menu item
function custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    unset($items['customer-logout']);
    $items['customer-logout'] = 'Logout';
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_my_account_menu_items', 999 );
```